# "Package LISP-UNIT is not loaded" error in Cusp Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, common-lisp, cusp

I'm getting the following error in Eclipse using the Cusp plug-in:

> Package LISP-UNIT is not loaded

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an error?  I found the following in google groups (first item if you google for that message):

> There is an option in preferences, which allows to turn using `lisp-unit` on or off.

lisp-unit seems to be a unit testing package.